# The Suggested Edit side-by-side comparison is cut off on the right side

Tags: bug, design, css

As you can see, in the suggested edit queue, the diff changes on the right are not all visible due to it being cut off. I replicated the bug in both Chrome 32, Safari 7.0.1, and Firefox 27.

If you run this, you can see all of the content:

```
$('.question-summary').css('width','955px');
```

---

[image: Suggested Edit cutoff top]

[image: Suggested Edit cutoff bottom]

Comment: same bug as [this](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2367/suggested-edit-css-bug) or a different one? "The right part is cut off (lines up with the sidebar from the main page)..."